# C++ Server/Client Chat Program

Tags: c++, sockets, network-programming

I am working on a server-multiclient chat program and made a method that prints input that a server types in to ALL its respective clients.

Method:

```
void *admin_handler (void *ptr) {
    char strBuf [100000];
    const char strExit [20] = "Server: terminated.";

    while(1) {
        scanf ("%s", strBuf);
        int i;
        for (i=0; i < nClient; i++){
            if (strcmp(strBuf,"Exit") == 0){
                write (nFDList [i], strExit, strlen (strExit) + 1);
                quick_exit (EXIT_SUCCESS);
            }
            else {
                write (nFDList [i], strBuf, strlen (strBuf) + 1);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

However, when I type in "Exit" on the server side, it only prints "Server: terminated." to the first client I open, while when I type in anything else, it prints the message from the server to all the clients. How can I get the server to print strExit to all of the clients like strBuf?

**NOTE: nFDList[i] is an array that stores the clients.**

Comment: Some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) should solve it. My main suggestion is that you separate the input-handling functionality, the "command" parsing functionality, and the sending-to-all functionality into separate functions. Should make it simpler to avoid such problems.

Comment: I just don't understand how my if statement's write doesn't work the same as the else statement write...the only difference is strBuf and strExit.

Comment: It works fine, to the first client. Then you exit. How could your program continue writing to all the other clients after it exits?

Comment: Thats what the write in the else statement does..it writes the server input to all clients

Comment: Then [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) in general. And especially learn how to step through your code line by line with a debugger. Then is will become obviously clear what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

To get it to print "Server: terminated." to all clients, I had to modify my code as follows:

```
void *admin_handler (void *ptr) {
    char strBuf [100000];
    const char strExit [20] = "Server: terminated.";
    while(1) {
        scanf ("%s", strBuf);
        int i;
        for (i=0; i < nClient; i++){
            if (strcmp(strBuf,"Exit") == 0){
                for (i=0; i < nClient; i++){
                    write (nFDList [i], strExit, strlen (strExit) + 1);
                }
                quick_exit (EXIT_SUCCESS);
            }
            else {
                write (nFDList [i], strBuf, strlen (strBuf) + 1);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since, as you rightly point out, the only difference between sending a normal message and the shutdown message is the text used in the sending, then you can "make what is true real" by having just the one occurrence of the sending logic, and manipulating the input.

Here is a suggested alternative that is more DRY:

```
void *admin_handler (void *ptr) {
    char strBuf [100000];
    char flagExit = 0;
    const char strExit [20] = "Server: terminated.";
    while(1) {
        scanf ("%s", strBuf);

        if (strcmp(strBuf, "Exit") == 0){
            strncpy(strBuf, strExit, strlen(strExit));
            flagExit = 1;
        }

        int i;
        for (i=0; i < nClient; i++){
            write (nFDList [i], strBuf, strlen (strBuf) + 1);
        }

        if (flagExit) {
            quick_exit (EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
    }
}
```